# Testing a python script in a specific version

Tags: python, tox

I currently have Python 2.6.2 installed on my mac. I am writing a script which MUST run on Python 2.5.2. So I want to write a python script, and test is specifically against 2.5.2 and NOT 2.6.2.

I was looking at virtualenv, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. I ran `python virtualenv.py TEST` which made a TEST dir, but it had python 2.6 in it. Is there a way to make virtualenv use a different version of python than what's installed default on my machine? Is another way to use the `#!` as the first line of the python script? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just install a Python 2.5.2.

I have 3 different versions Python installed on my Lucid and they use different links under `/bin/` so it's easy to call the specific version

python -> python3 ->python3.1
python2 -> python2.7
python2.5

Answer (score 13):

Check out [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/); it's designed to do exactly this.

Here is an example of using tox to run a `hello_world.py` script against multiple Python versions:

**Install tox**

```
pip install tox
```

**Create a tox.ini configuration file**

```
[tox]
envlist = py39, p310, p311

[testenv]
commands = python hello_world.py
```

- The envlist option specifies the Python versions to test against
- The commands option specifies the command to run in each environment

**Run tox**

```
tox
```

- This will create separate environments for Python 3.9, 3.10, and 3.11 and run the hello_world.py script in each environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a sandboxed environment with different python versions using virtualenv. As Kable has done, install the 2.5. version you want to test against. Then create your virtual environment:

```
virtualenv --p=python2.5 myapp
```

To get a clean environment you may use the --no-site-packages switch with the command above. Quite handy when trying to simulate a new, fresh setup. Now activate your virtualenv:

```
source myapp/bin/activate
```

If you check the python version you should now get version 2.5.x:

```
python -V
```

Now you can install modules as you like into your virtual environment in the usual fashion:

```
easy_install ... 
pip ...
```

To exit your virtual environment:

```
deactivate
```

Hope this may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

try `#!/path/to/your/python/version`

But make sure you execute the script from the terminal, and make it executable before hand: `chmod 755 myscript.py`

Answer (score 0):

Using **'virtualenv'** you can have different isolated Python environments on a single machine. Also you can switch any-time between the different python interpreter versions.

*What is virtualenv?*

A Virtual Environment is an isolated working copy of Python which allows you to work on a specific project without worry of affecting other projects. It enables multiple side-by-side installations of Python, one for each project. It doesn’t actually install separate copies of Python, but it does provide a clever way to keep different project environments isolated.

*How to install?*

```
pip install virtualenv
```

*To create virtual environment for python 2.7 :*

```
root:~# which python2.7

/usr/bin/python2.7
```

---

```
root:~# which python3.4

/usr/local/bin/python3.4
```

You can also use a Python interpreter of your choice:

```
root:~# virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 Vpy27

Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7

New python executable in /root/Vpy27/bin/python2.7

Also creating executable in /root/Vpy27/bin/python

Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
```

To begin using the virtual environment, it needs to be activated:

```
root:~# source Vpy27/bin/activate
```

The name of the current virtual environment will now appear on the left of the prompt:

```
(Vpy27) root:~# python -V
Python 2.7.3
```

Install packages as usual, for example:

```
(Vpy27) root:~# pip install junos-eznc    >> All pip installs done here, will be available only in this environment.
```

If you are done working in the virtual environment for the moment, you can deactivate it:

```
(Vpy27) root:~# deactivate
```

*To create virtual environment for python 3.4:*

```
root:~# which python3.4

/usr/local/bin/python3.4

root:~# virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.4 Vpy34

root:~# source Vpy34/bin/activate

(Vpy34) root:~# python -V
Python 3.4.4
```

There is also a way to create virtual environment with already available site-packages.