# Trouble switching between two Python 3.x versions

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I am new to Python, and I have been trying to follow their online tutorial which relies on the current version Python 3.10 being installed. I've tried several solutions to upgrade from 3.9.12 to the most recent 3.10.4, but all modes of calling python default to 3.9.12.

I am using a Mac, and I first tried to use homebrew with "brew install", but I've read that homebrew hasn't yet switched from 3.9. I next tried to update through Anaconda by running "conda install python=3.10.4", but Anaconda Navigator is still using 3.9 for all environments.

I know that 3.10.4 has been installed on my computer; however, I lack the skillset right now to find out where it is and how I can change the default to calling from wherever 3.10 is right now.

I would appreciate help with this! Please let me know ways that I could change the default version of python being called (whether in Anaconda or just through access via terminal). I've found a lot of resources for changing between python2 and python3, but not much for switching between python3 versions.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you switch between python 2 and 3, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340873/how-do-you-switch-between-python-2-and-3-and-vice-versa)

Comment: "and I have been trying to follow their online tutorial which relies on the current version Python 3.10 being installed. " I mean, you should mostly be able to complete the tutorial in Python 3.9 (maybe the added something for pattern matching, which is new in 3.10).

Comment: In any case, you should probably just create a new conda environment using the version you want, then activate that environment with conda

Comment: @Cyb3rst0rm that isn't helpful to the OP, who seems to already be using `conda` instead of `virtualenv`, adding that into the mix will only confuse things furhter

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - That was an auto-comment, I personally thought this was a dupe, flagged, and an auto-comment was created. I don't think I'll retract the flag though...

Comment: @Cyb3rst0rm yes, I know it was automatically commented.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - okay

Comment: I'm not familiar with Conda, but I've been using `pyenv` for a while and works pretty well. You install different versions `pyenv install x.xx.xx` and then set a global version (default `python3` and a local version (per project). IMHO it's the easiest way to work with different versions. You can change versions at any time with `pyenv shell`. I recommend this article that explains it all perfectly: https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Conda, but I would recommend `pyenv` to solve this exact problem. `pyenv` helps you manage different Python versions, and set different versions per project, or per shell. This is very useful when working on different project or testing different distributions.

You basically install with `brew` like

```bash
brew update
brew install pyenv
```

Then set your environment, with [these steps](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#set-up-your-shell-environment-for-pyenv). (It will depend on your shell).
Then you can start installing different versions like:

```bash
pyenv install 3.10.4
pyenv install 3.7.3
...
```

With versions installed, you can set the global, local and shell versions.

```bash
# This will set the default global python3 to the specified version
pyenv global 3.10.4

# This will set the default interpreter in a specific project/folder
pyenv local 3.7.3

# This will set the current shell to a specific version
pyenv shell 3.9.6
```

IMHO it's the easiest way to work with different versions.
Here's the [link to the official repo](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), and I would also suggest [this article from RealPython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv), that's explains it all in much greater detail.